# Forecasting with X13 Arima Statsmodels

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting, arima

i am trying to make a simple forecasting with X13 Arima model from statsmodels.
Here are the libs

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import os
```

Then i download (Windows executable with ASCII text file output) "x13as_ascii-v1-1-b59.tar" from https://www.census.gov/data/software/x13as/x13as-archive.html and define the path as

```
XPATH = "./x13as_ascii-v1-1-b59/x13as/"
```

I am using the simple dataset from statsmodels for co2 forecasting.

```
data =sm.datasets.co2.load_pandas().data
data.co2.interpolate(inplace=True)
data = data.resample('M').sum()
```

And if i trying to get the prediction with that code:

```
x13_arima = sm.tsa.x13_arima_select_order(data, x12path=XPATH)
```

I get this output:

```
c:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\x13.py:203: X13Warning: WARNING: At least one visually significant trading day peak has been
      found in the estimated spectrum of the regARIMA residuals.

WARNING: At least one visually significant trading day peak has been
      found in one or more of the estimated spectra.
warn(errors, X13Warning)
```

I actually using win 64 bit and the folder x13as has this files:

- docs
- testairline.spc
- x13as_ascii.exe

Comment: this is suggesting something with the data.  is the data correct (no outliers for example) ?

Comment: i checked it and the data is correct. i tried with another data and get the same output

Comment: so post this so others can replicate: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example